# Eclipse Android Developer Tools corrupts PhoneGap created project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

After following http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android to create a PhoneGap Android project like so:

./create ~/Dropbox/eclipse_workspace/DOTD_UK uk.co.dasque DOTD_UK

Using Eclipse (Android Developer Tools) v21.1.0 to create a new Project from Existing Code, I get the following:

Invalid project description.
  /Users/ed/Dropbox/eclipse_workspace/DOTD_UK overlaps the location of another project: 'DOTD_UK'

Any idea?

Comment: Have faced the same error on ADT v22/v21 + PhoneGap 2.7.0.

Comment: In my case, I just ended up to make a folder under Eclipse's default workspace and the error's gone: ./create ~/Documents/workspace/test-app ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a sure backup you can use, save the core files (assets, src, res, manifest, etc) and create another one. It's easier (and much faster) than fixing all references...

Comment: But is that a bug of PhoneGap that's known? I'd like to be able to create PhoneGap projects easily through that method.